# Extensions for simple modules over group algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ a field with field extension $L$ ($K$ perfect and $L$ finite field extension first for simplicity),
Let $S$ be a simple $KG$ module.
Viewed as a $LG$-module $S$ decomposes as a direct sum of simple $LG$-modules $L_l$.

> Question 1: Let $i \geq 1$ be fixed. Do we have $Ext_{KG}^i(S,S) \neq 0$ if and only if $Ext_{LG}^i(L_l,L_l) \neq 0$?

The $L_i$ should be Galois conjugates of each other so we should have $Ext_{LG}^i(L_l,L_l) \neq 0$ if and only if $Ext_{LG}^i(L_t,L_t) \neq 0$ for some $l \neq t$.

> Question 2: Does this property also hold for arbitrary (possibly infinite) field extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be the alternating group $A_4$, let $K=\mathbb{F}_2$, and $L=\mathbb{F}_4$. Then there are two non-trivial one dimensional simple $LG$-modules, say $S_1$ and $S_2$. These lie over a single two dimensional $KG$-module $S$, so extending the field on $S$ gives $S_1\oplus S_2$. Let $i=1$. Neither $S_1$ nor $S_2$ extends itself, but $S$ does because $S_1$ and $S_2$ extend each other. So the answer to question 1 is no.